# If the function $\sqrt{x} \sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

First confusion is $\sqrt x$ has a domain of $[0, \infty)$, how we can say anything on $\mathbb{R}$?

If for $[0, \infty)$ than it is a continuous function on $(0, \infty)$ but what about the point zero will it be uniformly continuous there are not?

Comment: It have limit $+\infty$.

Comment: could you  please frame your question better , it is hard to understand

Comment: Your first confusion is valid : clearly uniform continuity was meant only on the domain i.e. $[0,\infty)$. But it won't hold : as $x\to \infty$, try to use the fact that $\sqrt x \sin x$ is "too slopy". A higher slope means that points are close but their function values are far. Use the mean value theorem, our friend is certainly differentiable apart from $0$, which needs care.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take $x_n = n\pi$ and $y_n = n\pi + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and show that $|y_n-x_n| \to 0$ but $|f(y_n) - f(x_n)|\not\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.